# jQuery traversal .closest().find() not working? (with jsFiddle)

Tags: jquery, html, traversal

Am looking to find a certain div using jQuery traversing, and if that div has a specific class, show an alert.. http://jsfiddle.net/gfA4F/1/

Here's the HTML (the outer div is for templating purposes):

```
<div class="thisness">

<div class="container">
    <div class="btn-group dropdown options-btns mark-read">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm options-btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>>Item1</li>
        <li>>Item2</li>
        <li>>Item3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="btn-group dropdown options-btns mark-read">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm options-btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>>Item1</li>
        <li>>Item2</li>
        <li>>Item3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

...

</div>
```

And here's attempted traverse that needs to be corrected:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".thisness").on("show.bs.dropdown", ".options-btns", function () {

      var $this = $(this);

      var $that = $this.closest('.container').find('.glyphicon');

      if ($that.hasClass('.glyphicon-unchecked')) {alert('unchecked');}

      else if ($that.hasClass('.glyphicon-check')) {alert('check');}

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `.` in `hasClass` function because it is already looking for a class.

Try this:

```
if ($that.hasClass('glyphicon-unchecked')) {
    alert('unchecked');
} else if ($that.hasClass('glyphicon-check')) {
    alert('check');
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfA4F/4/)

Comment: Updated it :) didn't realize you had multiple `.container` so yes you do need `closest`